# Airflow execution_timeout resetting every retry

Tags: airflow

I want that the task fails after 12 hours it started, I have set `execution_timeout` to 12 hours:

Operator is SQLSensor, since it sometimes lost connection and fails, I set the `retries` to 3.

However, because of the retries, task starts over after every timeout.

1: task started at 10:00

2: timeout at 22:00

3: then task started again at 22:01

I don't want this, how can I set total timeout for all retries?

```
log_sensor = SqlSensor(
    task_id='log_sensor',
    conn_id='mssql_etl',
    sql=my_query,
    retries=3,
    execution_timeout=timedelta(hours=12),
    dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `sla` kwarg, as described in the documentation here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.2/code.html?highlight=task%20timeout

> **sla** *(datetime.timedelta)* – time by which the job is expected to succeed. Note that this represents the timedelta after the period is closed. For example if you set an SLA of 1 hour, the scheduler would send an email soon after 1:00AM on the 2016-01-02 if the 2016-01-01 instance has not succeeded yet. The scheduler pays special attention for jobs with an SLA and sends alert emails for sla misses. SLA misses are also recorded in the database for future reference. All tasks that share the same SLA time get bundled in a single email, sent soon after that time. SLA notification are sent once and only once for each task instance.

Comment: Actually I don't think so, I am using sla for alert mails as described in the documentation. When used sla, airflow sends an alert mail and task continues to be executing, it is for notification afaik. I want to timeout a task after a period, task should be failed when it timeout. When I set retries to 0, it does what I want. But there is a risk to lost connection any time. Because of this I have to set retries more than 0. When I set retries, it became up_for_retry after timeout.

Comment: Ah good point, I misunderstood what you are asking.  Have you considered setting a `dagrun_timeout` as described here? https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dag.py#L138-L141

Comment: Thanks but it does not meet my requirements, first of all it is for dag run but I need something for task instance, also my dag is not scheduled, and it is for scheduled dag runs :(
It is good to learn this, I can use it other scheduled dags :) thanks.